# @Repository @Resource and component scan issue in spring

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, inversion-of-control

I have two classes says A and B, B is annotated with @Repository annotation and A class has a reference variable of  B type annotated with @Resource type.I know the meaning of both annotations.

I am not using xml configuration. Do I need to put the  tag

```
<context-component-scan base-package = ""/>
```

to point out above classes or Spring will automatically scan the all class path.
I know this is a simple question but I am in confusions because

1. spring doc says, auto scan of class path
2. I have a large project and not able to find the entry for   for a particular case as given above (A and B class case)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Spring doesn't do component scanning if you don't tell it to.

You'll need to provide a `<component-scan>` element to scan for `@Component` (or the sub annotations) annotated types and have Spring generate corresponding bean definitions. Try to restrict the `base-package` so as not to get any unexpected results.